# AbstractTableModel: from cell to column and row header

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I have a table that extends AbstractTableModel, I have implemented a method to return the number of column and row of a double-clicked cell (in this way I can individuate univocally the cell in question).
I would like to have the column and the row header (row header= the text in first cell of every row) of a cell such determined.
Here the code for cell individuation:

```
table= new JTable(new MyTableModel());
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getClickCount() > 1) {
              int row = table.rowAtPoint(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
              int col = table.columnAtPoint(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));

                }
              }
    });
private class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {...}
```

Found the solution for column's name:

`System.out.println(table.getColumnName(col));`

Now we have to resolve for the rows.

And...Found the solution for rows:

```
System.out.println(table.getValueAt(row, 0));
```

"thank you" for my own help.. Wish that will be useful for others readers

Comment: If the rows or columns move, don't forget to [convert coordinates](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).

Comment: You're right, I will provide. Thank you